# Android ViewStub: Load all view data when just start onCreate?

Tags: android

If I have 4 buttons on top, when click any one of it, I will inflate the corresponding viewstub. All the viewstub are listview and will get data from server.
The questions is:

1. Should I load all the data (4 set of data) when just start
   onCreate? But the loading time will very long.
2. When should I load the data for each listview?
3. When I click the other button and go to other view, will all the data be lost(other listview)?
4. Will it cause memory problem because of loading too much data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I would use one list activity with 4 different adapters. I will create 4 instance variables for the list activity to save the different adapters.

So when I start the app, I will initialize the first adapter with its data and set it as instance variable and also set it to the list view.

Then I will follow the same steps for the other list only when the button is clicked for the first time. When any of these buttons are clicked again, I will set the adapter previously set to the instance variable to the listview.

1. No you should not load all the data. As it will just take too much time.
2. Load the data for the first list initially. For the other 3 options, only load data when their buttons are clicked for the first time.
3. If you store that data as an instance variable to the ListActivity then it will not be lost.
4. It can cause OOM memory if there is too much data. But for normal cases should be ok.

Comment: Thank you very much. if I would like to go from view1 to view2, I click button2, then, I should set view1 visibility to GONE. Am I correct?

Comment: If you absolutely want to show some sort of view swtiching, I recomend using a viewflipper to switch between views. Else just use one listview and keep setting different adapters to it when a button is clicked.

Comment: Actually, I just want to use viewStub to replace tabhost. You think viewFlipper is better than viewstub?

Comment: I guess its ok. I have not personally used ViewStub.